# How to create PySpark RDD from any database table?

Tags: pyspark

As i am new to Spark community, can anyone explain how to create PySpark RDD from database table. I can create PySpark RDD from CSV file using textFile() method of SparkContext method. But I don't know creating PySpark RDD from database table.

Comment: Loading the table outputs a Dataframe. Please see and example of [Dataframe to RDD conversion](https://towardsdatascience.com/a-modern-guide-to-spark-rdds-725cd7c14059#e69f)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using pyspark,

```
df = sqlContext.read.table("your_database.your_hive_table")
```

`df` (dataframe) will now have your rows that you can play with using Spark API.  For e.g.

```
df.select("*").show()  //equivalent to select * from your_hive_table

>>> df = sqlContext.read.table("students")
>>> df.select("*").show()
+----+---------+---+
|   a|        b|  c|
+----+---------+---+
| Jon|  English| 80|
| Amy|Geography| 70|
|Matt|  English| 90|
| Jon|     Math|100|
| Jon|  History| 60|
| Amy|   French| 90|
+----+---------+---+
```

Comment: Thanks for replying..Now i could use df (dataframe) to create RDD data structure if i want it in RDD structure. right?

Comment: `df.rdd` will give you the dataframe as `rdd`. Check the documentation.